# Gentran server port mapper error

Tags: edi

Let me preface this question with I am new to the EDI world and Gentran.

I have Gentran running on a Sun Solaris 10 server.  I am trying to connect to that instance from a Windows 7 server using the Gentran server GUI.  When I try to connect I get port mapper errors.  The error reads;
WinRPC: Port mapper failure.
Winsock: Error 7.
sub-error: Authentication error.
When I click ok on the error I receive this;
It_connect: Namebroker not found on host namebroker. Port mapper failure, Authentication error.

The namebroker is running on the Sun server and I have insured rpc/bind is up and running as well.  I saw rquotad running on the production server from the command rpcinfo command so I started on the DR environment.

I have looked for an answer but it has eluded me.  IBM told me to have the Unix admin start the port mapper.  I am the Unix admin and port mapper is running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might check with the folks over at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found that rpcbind was only setup locally with the help of this forum;
http://www.unix.com/solaris/228033-rpcinfo-cant-contact-portmapper-rpc-authentication-error-why-failed-unspecified-error.html

after failing to get rpcinfo from the server2 running the command from server1;

server1$ rpcinfo -p server2
rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Authentication error; why = Failed (unspecified error)

I followed these instructions;

Check output on host you are trying to get RPC info from (server1) :
Code:
svcprop network/rpc/bind:default | grep -i local

If it returns config/local_only boolean true , then put it to false via svccfg.

Code:
svc:> select network/rpc/bind

svc:/network/rpc/bind> setprop config/local_only=false

svc:/network/rpc/bind> quit

root@host:~# svcadm refresh /network/rpc/bind

root@host:~# svcprop network/rpc/bind:default | grep -i local

config/local_only boolean false

The rpcinfo -p command should work now.